# Why doesn't the test work without if __name__ == '__main__'?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-unittest

I can't figure out why without the line `if __name__ == '__main__':` before `unittest.main()` the test does not find?

I am using the latest version of PyCharm. I know that in order for the test to work in PyCharm, you can not add these lines at all, but I want to deal with the logic itself: why without the line `if __name__ == '__main__':` the result is as in the screenshot, but if you add it, then everything works?

Code:

```
import unittest
from name_function import get_formatted_name


class NamesTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """Tests for 'name_function.py'."""

    def test_first_last_name(self):
        """Are names like 'Janis Joplin' working correctly?"""
        formatted_name = get_formatted_name('janis', 'joplin')
        self.assertEqual(formatted_name, 'Janis Joplin')


unittest.main()
```

There is only one function in the name_function module:

```
def get_formatted_name(first, last):
    """Builds a formatted full name."""
    full_name = f"{first} {last}"
    return full_name.title()
```

Result:

> No tests were found
>
> /Users/xxx/Documents/PycharmProjects/Book/venv/bin/python
> "/Applications/PyCharm
> CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pycharm/_jb_unittest_runner.py"
> --path /Users/xxx/Documents/PycharmProjects/Book/testing.py
> Testing started at 00:22 ...
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------> Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
>
> OK
> Launching unittests with arguments python -m unittest
> /Users/xxx/Documents/PycharmProjects/Book/testing.py in
> /Users/xxx/Documents/PycharmProjects/Book
>
> Process finished with exit code 0
>
> Empty suite
>
> Empty suite

I am running the testing.py module as the main program, but judging by the answer line PyCharm is running the test via `python -m unittest testing.NamesTestCase`

I additionally checked the value of the global variable `__name__` and indeed it has the value `testing`, as if `testing` was imported. Although I launch it initially.

Please explain why in this case the startup script differs from the standard one and when `testing.py` starts it runs it through `unittest`? I really want to finally understand this issue. Also don't understand why, in this case, if it initially runs through `unittest`, `unittest.main()` doesn't run normally without additional checking `if __name__ == '__main__':`?

Comment: When you remove the if statement the call to unittest.main() happens when you are imported.   The unittest will call main itself.  Just remove the call if you remove the if statement.

Comment: Restated: You want `unittest.main()` to run only when your module is run, but not when it is imported. 
 When you remove the if statement the call to `unittest.main()` happens when you are imported, which you don't want.

Comment: Can't figure out why `unittest.main()` won't run without `if __name__ == '__main__' :`?
I successfully imported the `unittest` module into my `testing.py` module.

Comment: And also why the global variable `__name__` is value 'testing' in this case? After all, this is my `testing.py` module, which I run and into which I imported other modules such as `unittest`. And it turns out that the main `unittest` module is launched instead of my `testing.py`

Comment: This is the point.  When the module is run directly, `__name__` has the value `"__main__"` but when it is imported, `__name__` has the string value of the module itself.  The way unittest works, is it scans your module for function names that start with `test_` to find the test functions, then it imports your module to be able to execute those methods and get their return values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks like I'm starting to get the point.
Am I correct in understanding that in this case, when I run my `testing.py` module, into which the `unittest` module is imported, then it is the `unittest` module that runs as main with the value `"__main__"` and eventually imports my `testing.py` module? Is this such a feature of this case?
The author of the book I'm learning from does this at Geany.
In Geany, this test runs on a single line of `unittest.main()` without the `if __name__ == '__main__':`
Is it related to some peculiarities of the PyCharm interpreter?